# Can I trust the firebase admin token creator to not steal my token holdings?

Tags: trust

I created a contract for over 3 million eth and now I'm trying to develop on Google cloud but worry that they might try to change the contract. But I'm not necessarily sure they can edit the contract without my permission. Since Im in control of my project I can change roles. So basically I wanna know if I did the right thing by denying them admin role to my project.

I changed some of their roles and permission. Should I trust them to help me or will they just try to pull a fast one on me.